# WPF UserControl as CustomReportItem

Tags: reporting-services

Is there any way to use a WPF UserControl as a CustomReportItem for SSRS? In the draw method I'd like to create an instance of the WPF control and render it as a visual brush. The only problem is that WPF control can only be instanced in an STA environment. Creating a new thread in the STA environment in order to create the control works in VisualStudio, but deployed to the SQL Server, almost every time the thread starts in MTA mode - even though it was set to STA before it started.

I know that starting an STA thread in an SQL Server context shouldn't be possible anyway - but is there really no solution for this problem?

BR,

Tristan

Answer (score 0):

No, there only component that provides access to SSRS is the "ReportViewer Control for Visual Studio". BUt you can also interact with SSRS with SOAP and UrlAccess

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153697.aspx